# Sequence of function and continuity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can we find a sequence of continuous function which converges everywhere but is discontinuous everywhere or atlease we can find example with condition wherever it converges?

Comment: As to Q2, the (pointwise) limit of a sequence of (real-valued) continuous functions is called a Baire class 1 function, and such functions have a dense set of points where tey are continuous. So no, in that case.

Comment: Pointwise convergence?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma thanks can you please give some reference for Baire class 1 function and theorem: such function are continuous on dense set of points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions is a Baire (class) one function (by definition; class 2 is pointwise limits of those etc.). Such functions have a dense set of points of continuity, see [this survey](https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/SeniorProjectArchive/2007/huh.pdf) e.g. This shows that we cannot find an everywhere discontinuous function this way. In fact, the set of points of continuity is of second category in any complete metric space, see [theorem 2.2 here](http://math.ucsd.edu/programs/undergraduate/1213_honors_presentations/Siuyung_Fung_Honors_Thesis.pdf). It's pretty classical.